# xmlbuilder2 set text and attribute using JS object

Tags: node.js

I am using xmlbuilder2 to create an XML document from a JS object.

This works just fine:

```
const { create } = require('xmlbuilder2');

const obj = {
  root: {
    '@att': 'val',
    foo: {
      bar: 'foobar'
    },
    baz: {}
  }
};

const doc = create(obj);
const xml = doc.end({ prettyPrint: true });
console.log(xml);
```

However, I want to get the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root att="val">
  <foo>
    <bar myattr="hello">foobar</bar>
  </foo>
  <baz/>
</root>
```

How do I set both the attribute and content for the `bar` element?
I did not find any examples online, I've tried using `@text` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I did not find any examples online"* - Well... https://oozcitak.github.io/xmlbuilder2/object-conversion.html#text

Comment: I am stupid :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (with the help of Tomalak!) that the correct way is to do:

```
const { create } = require('xmlbuilder2');

const obj = {
  root: {
    '@att': 'val',
    foo: {
      bar: {"@myattr":"hello", "#":'foobar'}
    },
    baz: {}
  }
};

const doc = create(obj);
const xml = doc.end({ prettyPrint: true });
console.log(xml);
```